# Get specific part of data using http.request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

I want get a specific part of the response data got using http.request.
I have a url that is of a 50 mb zip file
I want to use 5 request asynchronously to get the data to make download faster.
My plan is simple request 1 will get 0-10mb of data while request 2 is getting 11-20 mb and so on.
Is there any way to do it in node js.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: That won't necessarily make your download faster. With each request the download rate decreases

Comment: Read about the **range header field**.

Comment: is there any way to make download faster in node js? for example using multi-thread like **aria2c** or **idm** does. they use upto 16 threads for a download

Comment: https://github.com/zulhilmizainuddin/multipart-download https://github.com/tejom/parallelized_http

Comment: @lumio That's [**not entirely true**](https://superuser.com/questions/261663/why-is-multi-thread-downloading-faster-than-single-thread).

Comment: @ImtiazChowdhury thanks for the link. Didn't know that :)